# Кастомный SELECT

Tags: html, css

По дизайну нужно сделать "резиновый" селект с 3-мя разными фонами (Иконка слева, стрелка справа, градиент на фоне).
Посредством CSS получилось только в Хроме сделать. Mozilla, IE не реагируют.

```
  select{
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 33px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
  #os_rf{
  background: url(../img/icons_inner/monitor-icn.svg), 
              url(../img/icons_inner/triangle.svg),
              url(../img/select_bg.jpg);
  background-position: 8px 13px, right 10px top 50%, 0 0;
  background-repeat:  no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#os_rf:focus{
  background: url(../img/icons_inner/monitor-icn_orange.svg), 
              url(../img/icons_inner/triangle.svg),
              url(../img/select_bg.jpg);
  background-position: 8px 13px, right 10px top 50%, 0 0;
  background-repeat:  no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Перебрал кучу решений, так ничего не подошло, может кто решал такую задачу?

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы покажите, что у вас получилось, тогда желающих помочь будет побольше.

Comment: Показал, код и результат

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Помогут вот такие стили для селекта (кроме IE)

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;    
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: '';
```

Comment: Действительно, для мозилы помогло, спасибо. А как быть с IE? И вертикально выровнять текст можно только padding'ом?

Comment: Соберите, пожалуйста, пример на jsFiddle. Мне лень все с 0 верстать.

Answer (score 3):

Вот библиотека: [flamedJS](https://github.com/FlamesoFF/flamedJS).

Там есть кастомный селект. Делается очень просто. А CSS-ом select стилизуется только в паре брузеров и то криво.